# Tensor Product of Fractional Ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Reading Neukirch's book on algebraic number theory and on chapter III he calls the class group by the name of "Picard Group". This group, for me, had to do with invertible ideals modulo isomorphism. However I can sense there is some equivalence in the definitions here and I'm trying to write it down.

It appears to me that I have to prove the existence of some canonical isomorphism between
\begin{equation}
    M \otimes N \xrightarrow{\sim}MN
\end{equation}
where $M$, $N$ are two fractional ideals and $MN$ is their product in $K$. This would of course imply that fractional ideals are invertible, and that the group operations are compatible so it seems very natural to ask for this isomorphism to exist (However there is a possibility that this isomorphism is only defined up to multiplication by an element of $K^*$).

I imagine this would be $\mu: M \otimes N \to MN$ that takes $\mu(m\otimes n) = mn$, but of course this is not bijective in general and I have no reason to believe this would be except that I *want* it to be.

**Q:**

1. Is this map an isomorphism?
2. Is *some* map $M \otimes N \to MN$ an isomorphism?

Comment: In a Dedekind domain, any invertible module is isomorphic to an ideal, and isomorphism of modules corresponds to equivalence of ideals. For ideals in a Dedekind domain then this $\mu$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think one can argue that everything in $M\otimes N$ can be taken to be a pure tensor by shuffling things around (this depends on the fact that $K$ is the fraction field) and then the map is obviously injective.

Comment: Ah! Yes since all fractional ideals are - up to $K^*$ - an actual ideal, this then follows quite simply.

Comment: @AnginaSeng You said that any invertible module is isomorphic to an ideal. Is there any reference for this? I'm quite interested in that implication.

Comment: This follows easily from the classification of f.g. modules over a Dedekind domain. Each is the direct sum of a projective module and a torsion module, and a non-trivial projective module is the direct sum of a free module and an ideal. @solov.t